# MySQL query with DISTINCT on multiple columns and order by date (last timestamp)

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling in a query with a SELECT DISTINCT on day_number but ordered by a date timestamp.

New records are added weeekly, and I only need the one with the latested insert date (date_add) and ordered by day_number.

```
id   Dept_id  day_number   price     date_add
1      46         1        20000    2019-08-19 17:06:30
2      46         2        18000    2019-08-19 17:06:30
3      46         3        19000    2019-08-19 17:06:30
4      46         4        16000    2019-08-19 17:06:30
5      46         5        18000    2019-08-19 17:06:30
6      46         6        22000    2019-08-19 17:06:30
7      46         7        30000    2019-08-19 17:06:30
10     46         1        38000    2019-08-19 17:15:24
11     46         1        34000    2019-08-19 17:18:44
```

I tried this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT day_number, date_add, (price)
FROM ai_targets where dept_id=46
GROUP BY day_number
ORDER BY day_number DESC
```

but it gave wrong price.

Comment: Not sure about the expected results here.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for tips/tools how to generated the expected results.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the row with the maximum `day_number` for each `date_add` use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM ai_targets *
WHERE dept_id = 46
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM ai_targets
  WHERE dept_id = t.dept_id AND date_add = t.date_add AND day_number > t.day_number
)
```

If you want the row with the maximum `date_add` for each `day_number`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM ai_targets *
WHERE dept_id = 46
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM ai_targets
  WHERE dept_id = t.dept_id AND day_number = t.day_number AND date_add > t.date_add
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following query?

```sql
    SELECT 
      * 
    FROM
      ai_targets t1 
    WHERE DATE_ADD= 
      (SELECT 
        MAX(DATE_ADD) 
      FROM
        ai_targets 
      WHERE t1.`day_number` = day_number 
        AND LEFT(t1.date_add, 10) = LEFT(DATE_ADD, 10) 
      GROUP BY LEFT(DATE_ADD, 10),
        day_number) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.day_number, t.date_add, (t.price)
FROM ai_targets t
INNER JOIN 
          (
            SELECT MAX(date_add) AS max_datea_dd 
            FROM ai_target
         ) mx 
         ON ma.max_date_add = t.date_add
where t.dept_id=46
GROUP BY t.day_number
ORDER BY t.day_number DESC;
```